# Do pro players manage to consistently maintain high CS in early game?

Tags: league-of-legends

As an ADC, I made a goal of getting 70 CS at the 10 minute mark. I can achieve this only in games where I have a very passive farming lane (rarely). Most of the time, there is a lot of harassing and some kills (normal games, I am Silver), and I get a lot lower CS then.

My question is: do pro players manage to keep their high CS score early game (around 10m) in a very aggressive lane? To rephrase it: whatever the CS they can achieve on a passive lane, does that drop much on an aggressive lane, or do they manage to keep the same CS score?

Edit: the reason I want to know this is to know whether or not I must be concern of the drop in my CS on aggressive lanes (I know 70 CS is actually low, I will set it higher when I achieve it).

Comment: So your asking on the differences of cs in passive and aggressive lane? or whether competitive players have the same cs no matter what? or how they have a consistently high cs? or... what?

Comment: 10cs/min is considered average for a professional player. They will rarely drop below that unless they legitimately cannot farm due to the lane setups.

Comment: I am asking if competitive players have a difference in cs in lane between passive and aggressive lanes and if yes, how much?

Comment: There aren't any noticable differences in a pro aggressive vs passive lane phase. Usually pro adcs just focus on farming while the supports trade. You'll notice them go more aggressive if the enemy is caught out of position, they receive a gank, and/or they finish a core item (blood thirster, trinity force, infinity edge, etc). In lower tiers this is the other way around, the adc is usually more aggressive while the support follows up on that aggressiveness. [These](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeGtVfZD9LVttCJzjIJLY1g) lectures were of GREAT benefit to me and may help you out as well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Competitive players do not drop CS, generally.

On offense, a competitive player will time his aggressive pushes with two things in mind. Firstly, he doesn't want to miss out on his own CS. That is the most important thing. Secondly, he wants to try to push his opponent out of lane when his opponent should be taking his CS, so that the opponent misses creeps.

On defense, a competitive player will be trying to make sure they're in as safe a position as possible when the creep wave is coming, so that they don't miss out on CS.

The combination of these things does tend to make for lanes where both sides are essentially freefarming each other for long stretches, with occasional bursts of intense action.

Professional mid laners and ADCs tend to average around 100 CS per 10 minutes, while top laners will get slightly less possibly due to roaming or due to the nature of their champion not being well-equipped to take *every* creep.

Edit:

[image: Creep Score]

Comment: Just for extra info. At 10min the wave of minions will be the 18th and the amount of minions out the door would be 114 that is equals to 2365 Gold (on minion only) + 1138 per 10min time. [Source](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111226174831/leagueoflegends/images/6/65/Perfect_Creep_Score.png)

Comment: `does tend to make for lanes where both sides are essentially freefarming each other for long stretches, with occasional bursts of intense action.`  My question is about when there isn’t a standoff and both sides are just happy to free farm. What happens when They are bullied or are bulling in lane, do they manage to be safe/be bully and still farm as well as when they are *left alone* to farm? Or that scenario doesn’t happen in high level games, and everyone is just `free farming with occasional bursts of intense action`.

Comment: @bolov You asked about professional players. Professional players don't play the same way that you do at Silver level.

Comment: ok I understand that. How about when they smurf? The other side will probably sometimes play like that. Are the pros then happy to drop the cs to counter the aggression or for getting kills or they just farm and farm and farm?

Comment: @bolov You are going out-topic. If they smurf or whatever ... they are not playing "for real" so, they shouldn't really care on how they play. Keep in mind that CS is a **very important** thing. you don't give up on that easily. As you can see, only from cs, at 10min you have extra 2.365 Gold, that is far more than 4 or even 6 kills (you get 100~300 per kill (besides FB)). They are aggressive always when they don't have minions to kill.

Comment: @Michel that's what I needed to know, ty

Comment: Professional players on smurf accounts can deal with constant harassment by freezing the lane under their own tower for safe farming, and pushing super hard all at once before backing to heal so they don't miss a wave.

Comment: If you **ONLY** get 70 at 10min, and when you only have a specific lane layout (passive), you need to learn how to do cs more efficiently. You're probably missing a lot of cs, even if the lane isn't being aggressive. There's 114 minions out at 10min range mark. You miss 44 minions. That is a LOT, a pro wouldn't miss that much even with an arm behind his back

Comment: I know 70 CS is not much. I want to set goals and when I achieve them I set higher goals. I just wanted to know if it is ok to have less cs if the lane is aggressive or should I want the same cs no matter what the lane layout is.

Comment: @bolov You want almost the same (maybe 5 or even 10 (depending on your support) missing. But not beyond that). The idea of "goals" is excellent. go for it =)

Comment: When I play adc I always shove my lane (unless the jungler is camping and/or I don't have any ward coverage) and I find it easier to farm because the enemy adc has to spend more time focusing on last hitting the minions and miss more if they go to poke. If you can get them under turret without them freezing the lane (caitlyn is very good at doing this) you can use their turret to "deny" them cs, thus getting you ahead in lane. You just need to be very careful about mid roams and jungle ganks. Wards are a MUST if you do this, tri bush and in front of dragon to be specific.